# DateTime.ParseExact "Hmmssff" FormatException

Tags: c#, .net

Why can't .Net parse:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("9301015", "Hmmssff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but it can parse this?

```
DateTime.ParseExact("9:301015", "H:mmssff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The first code block throws a System.FormatException

Comment: Isn't H in 24-hr format?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Yes - but "9" is valid in both cases since a single "h" or "H" indicates a 1-or-2-digit hour.